# Python SSL requests and Let's Encrypt certs

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, python-requests, lets-encrypt

I'm struggling at the moment to get the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library to perform a simple `GET` request to a site of mine with a [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) certificate. All's well with the site and I can access it from Chrome just fine. (I'm running OSX El Capitan at the moment).

First I tried doing a `GET` request to the site:

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get('https://example.com')
```

This gives me:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
```

I then tried various things, including getting hold of the [Let's Encrypt authority certificate](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/), and the following `openssl` command verifies my site's certificate successfully:

```
> openssl s_client -CAfile ./letsencryptauthorityx1.pem -connect example.com:443
```

The output of which included the following towards the bottom:

```
...
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: ...
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: ...
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1452865123
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Perhaps I'm missing something here, but it looks to me as though my site's been verified according to the Let's Encrypt authority certificate I supplied. So, I happily changed my Python code to:

```
>>> requests.get('https://example.com', verify='./letsencryptauthorityx1.pem')
```

But I still keep getting the `requests.exceptions.SSLError` error. I've also tried using the `DER` format of the authority certificate, but then I get the following error from `requests`:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: unknown error (_ssl.c:2825)
```

Can anybody perhaps educate me as to how to go about fixing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like your CA CERTS on the machine are not up to date or the web server is not configured to server the full certificate chain.

Comment: I'm using OSX (El Capitan). I've tried adding the ISRG Root X1 cert (as per https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18677?locale=en_US) and making it fully trusted across the entire system, but it still gives the same CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error.

Comment: Can you send as a private message your hostname with that cert? I just reinstalled my Mac using MAC OS X El Capitan and it works straight out of the box without installing any CAs. I think the web server is not properly configured to use the complete certificate chain. The reason why it's not failing with openssl is because you give the CA directly on the CLI.

Comment: You're right actually. If I configure the web server to use the full cert chain, it works like a charm! Please edit your answer here, or add a different answer, to include the advice on using the complete cert chain in the web server and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

For any lost soul that stumbled upon this post while looking for a **Windows** Fix for this issue.

Using Chrome:

1. Open the URL in using HTTPS.
2. On the address bar click where it says "Secure".
3. Click on certificate.
4. Go to the "Certification Path" tab.
5. Select "Let's Encrypt Authority X3" (Go up one level) then click "View Certificate".
6. Go to the "Details" tab and click "Export to File".
7. On the Wizard click next and select "Base-64 encoded X.509 (.CER)", click next again.
8. Select a folder and name for the file (Remember this directory).
9. Go to that folder and right click the certificate and click "Install Certificate".
10. Select Local Machine (Requires Admin Rights), click next.
11. Select "Automatically select the certificate store..." (Default), click next.
12. Click Finish.
13. Run your Python Script again.

Disclaimer: Using Chrome 67.0.3396.99 with Windows 10 64-Bit.

Answer (score 1):

On OSX you can export all the certs in your keychain access to a .pem file and then point requests to that file: http://movingpackets.net/2015/03/18/telling-openssl-about-your-root-certificates/

```
CA_BUNDLE = path_to_your_exported_file.pem
response = requests.get(user_account_url, verify=CA_BUNDLE)
```