# MQTT over TLS Verification Error in Python (no error in C# and Mqtt.fx)

Tags: c#, python-3.x, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I have a Mosquitto server configured to use MQTT over TLS, using the following configuration, with certificates and keys generated through certbot:

```
user mosquitto
listener 1883 localhost
listener 8883
cafile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.mqtt.domain/chain.pem
keyfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.mqtt.domain/privkey.pem
certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.mqtt.domain/cert.pem
```

I'm having trouble with the paho python client and mosquitto-clients (mosquitto_sub and mosquitto_pub), whereas I have no trouble at all using the M2MQTT client in C# or MQTT.fx GUI client (which uses Paho Java client).

The following is my python code:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import ssl

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

# chain.pem is the exact same file of the mosquitto configuration 
# /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.mqtt.domain/chain.pem
client.tls_set(ca_certs="chain.pem", certfile=None, keyfile=None,
               cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2, ciphers=None)

client.connect("my.mqtt.domain", 8883, 60)
```

And the following is the error I get trying to run this code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "subscriber.py", line 26, in <module>
    client.connect("my.mqtt.domain", 8883, 60)
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 839, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 994, in reconnect
    sock.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python3\lib\ssl.py", line 1108, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)
```

while on the server side I get the following:

```
1540452676: OpenSSL Error: error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca
1540452676: OpenSSL Error: error:140940E5:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:ssl handshake failure
```

I would have thought of a configuration error server side, but if I try to use a C# client, with M2MQTT, I have no problem at all:

```
MqttClient client = new MqttClient("my.mqtt.domain", 
    MqttSettings.MQTT_BROKER_DEFAULT_SSL_PORT, 
    true, 
    new X509Certificate("chain.pem"), 
    null, 
    MqttSslProtocols.TLSv1_2);

byte code = client.Connect(new Guid().ToString());

Console.WriteLine(code);
var message = "message";
client.Publish("test", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message), 2, true);
```

and, all the same, no issue at all with Mqtt.fx:

[image: Mqtt.fx client configuration]

All the same, trying

```
openssl s_client -connect my.mqtt.domain:8883 -CAfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.mqtt.domain/chain.pem
```

works fine, with no error and return code 0 for the verification.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Try  `fullchain.pem` not `chain.pem`

Comment: Hi, I just tried and using `fullchain.pem` is no use: python code gives the same error, and C# & Mqtt.fx keep working.

Comment: Sorry, missed it earlier, you should be using full chain in the mosquitto.conf as well iirc

Comment: Unfortunately, same errors and nothing changes.

Comment: Sounds like you need to import the LetsEncrypt CA authority certs into python SSL trusted keys register. See perhaps here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39356413/how-to-add-a-custom-ca-root-certificate-to-the-ca-store-used-by-python-in-window#39358282. And here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34812787/python-ssl-requests-and-lets-encrypt-certs

Comment: Thank you barny, I tried using directly the output of the ca file output of `python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.get_default_verify_paths())"`. Turns out that the `fullchain.pem` certificates generated by certbot are not enough for paho-mqtt and it needs the root certificate from Lets Encrypt.

Answer (score 0):

certificate has some thing error;
Perhaps python make a strict check

when you use openssl s_client, did you unstand all the message which s_client echoed.
I have meet some trouble with test ssl communication, finnally, I found the certifacte
has wrong time like "not before" or "not after" etc error,

Comment: Hi, [this is the output](https://pastebin.com/asbn68zs) of the s_client. It looks fine to me, as the SSL handshake completes correctly and the verification gets no error.

Comment: you certificate has two depth, you should use "wireshark" check the really pack